# How to make rectangle with my text inside bold, underlined

Tags: cv

My name is Georgios Giannakopoulos and I'm brand new to LaTeX.
I’m trying to make the following few things in LaTeX for my CV, but I don’t know what I’m doing wrong.

The first thing:
I’m trying to make a rectangle with my name in it and to be on that blue color and the picture to be on the left upper corner
And of course, my details
[image]

The second thing which I’m trying to do is to make a rectangle with a black line and the text below inside it

[image]

The third which I’m trying to do is to make the words “ *immediate availability” in red color including the underline to be in red.
Then to tabulate a couple of those certifications which I’m currently working on.

[image]

The fourth thing is very similar to the second
[image]

And the last thing is more complicated than the second and the fourth

[image]

I would be grateful if you can provide support on how to make for those 5 issues the source code

Thank you very much for your time and forward to hearing from you

Met vriendelijke groet / Kind Regards,
Georgios Giannakopoulos

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // For my understanding: Where did you get the screenschots from? Can you please edit your question and add this piece of information? Thanks // Do you know the various CV-templates at CTAN: https://ctan.org/topic/cv?lang=en ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E.! Do you want to use LaTeX or ConTeXt? These are two different TeX engine, your post is tagged 'ConTeXt' and you are speaking of 'LaTeX'. Btw, you should split your five questions in different questions. Some of them might have already an anwer on TeX S.E. If you have some piece of code, please join them, so that we could help you further.

Comment: I've removed the ConTeXt tag because your question revolves around LaTeX. Feel free to add it again if your question accepts a [ConTeXt](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page) answer.

Comment: If you want tu use LaTeX to have a CV that looks nice, imho do not try to imitate what is done in MS-Word. Have a look at the `moderncv` package.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you for your advice. However, I just found that the rectangle is
 \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=white]
 \centering
 {{\Huge}\textbf{\LARGE Georgios Giannakopoulos}}
 \end{mdframed}

 Now I'm trying to fill the rectangle with my name with RGB 0,112, 192
 In addition, I'm trying to move the rectangle upwards

Comment: difficult to answer without knowing the flow of your code and  the CV package being used

Comment: Note that the broader your question is, the harder it is for others to answer. Almost always, there exist more than one way to get the desired result and it is therefore cruicial for others to know at least the document environment that you are intending to use. This is the reason, why on this site it is typically required to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far, because it helps others tremendously to understand the specific problem you have and enables them to provide a valid and helpful answer.